# Jquery issue with .click() with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.addphoto', function(e){
    currentImgCnt = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#photo-update'+currentImgCnt).click();
});
```

Here `photo-update` is a dynamically generated input of type file, and `.addphoto` is also a dynamically generated button, the code is self explanatory. Once the person clicks the `.addphoto` button, it in turn clicks the `#photo-uplate` button

The problem is jQuery won't click the inner generated button that is the `#photo-update` button but the dynamically generated `.addphoto` button works fine.

JSFiddle HERE http://jsfiddle.net/z8yzbb41/3/

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
when I used $(".input-container").on('change','input',function () { alert('helo'); });

Comment: Recreate it in a fiddle pls

Comment: can you put this codein a jsfiddle?

Comment: one reason could be that for the dynamically generated `photo-update` element the id format might be different

Comment: you are writing `$('#photo-update'+currentImgCnt).click();` but there is no `.click()` event for `#photo-update` in jquery in jsfiddle..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z8yzbb41/3/

Comment: Not sure but i think you need this http://jsfiddle.net/z8yzbb41/4/

Comment: still $(document).on('click', '#photo-update'+currentImgCnt, function(e){ method wont work on dynamically generated inputs
you can see its not throwing an alert the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".input-container").on('change','input',function () { alert('helo'); });` Solved my problem